# jquery load data

Tags: jquery

dumbest question ever... but I want to somehow fill 'gid' value in data load

```
gid  = 123;
from = 33;
to   = 44;

$('#x').load('y', {'range['+gid+'][]' : [from , to]});
```

so I could get

```
[range] => Array
        (
            [123] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 33
                    [1] => 44
                )

        )
```

but with this syntax 'range['+gid+'][]' I get 'missing : after property id'. I'm desperate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use calculated property names for the left-hand side of an initializer in an object literal. So instead of:

```
$('#x').load('y', {'range['+gid+'][]' : [from , to]});
```

do this:

```
var options = {};
options['range['+gid+'][]'] = [from , to];
$('#x').load('y', options);
```

...because you *can* use calculated property names with the `[]` notation for setting object properties.